# Most Efficient Implementation of Spreadsheet Data

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

I do a lot of work with very large spreadsheet data (most of which is numeric data). I have been using nested lists to work with the data, accessing attributes by their index. I have recently been told that this is not a very efficient way to work with this type of data.

I am curious if there is a more efficient way of structuring this type of data using Dictionaries.

For instance, if I have a spreadsheet that would normally look like this as nested lists:

```
sheet = [['ACCOUNT', 'VALUE1', 'VALUE2', 'VALUE3'],
        ['Account1', '3.4332', '2.524', '4,567.23'],
        ['Account2', '1,235.67', '8.98', '4,321.78']]
```

How could I set this up using (nested?)Dictionaries so that I can access values by an "Account" key and a "Header" key? (basically easily access Account1, Value2)

I'd prefer the implementation to be efficient from a performance standpoint when iterating over accounts and extracting account/value pairs to compare/mutate. (I do lots of analysis on arrays from one day to the next, where the array structure remains the same, but the numeric data changes).

Comment: Have you actually run into performance issues with your current approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
row_iter = iter(sheet)
keys = next(row_iter)[1:]
data = {}
for row in row_iter:
    data[row[0]] = dict(zip(keys, row[1:]))
```

creates the dictionary

```
{'Account1': {'VALUE1': '3.4332', 'VALUE2': '2.524', 'VALUE3': '4,567.23'},
 'Account2': {'VALUE1': '1,235.67', 'VALUE2': '8.98', 'VALUE3': '4,321.78'}}
```

You can now access field by e.g. `data['Account1']['VALUE2']`.

Comment: For me, the code for `data['Account1']['VALUE2']` is much easier to read, but--not counting the overhead of constructing the dictionaries--is it more "efficient"?  Seems like one 2D array is going to take less space and perform faster than nested dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

```
sheet = {'Account1': {'Value1': '3.4332', 'Value2': '2.524', 'Value3': '4,567.23'},
         'Account2': {'Value1': '1,235.67', 'Value2': '8.98', 'Value3': '4,321.78'}}

>>> sheet['Account1']['Value2']
'2.524'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use numpy. That package has a very efficient implementation of 2d arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I'd store the data in a 2d matrix, then use dictionaries to find columns/rows by name.

Answer (score 1):

If your column headers don't change often, you might be best with actually combining the two - use a dictionary for the rows, but keep lists with integer indices for the columns in each row. For instance:

```
columns = {'VALUE1': 1, 'VALUE2': 2, 'VALUE3': 3}
sheet = {
         'Account1': ['3.4332', '2.524', '4,567.23'],
         'Account2': ['1,235.67', '8.98', '4,321.78'],
        }
```

This allows you to not have to store the column names repeatedly as dictionary keys, while still giving you the quick lookup for account names.

A lookup would look like this:

```
val = sheet['Account1'][columns['VALUE2']]
```

---

A `dict` of `namedtuple`s would also be a way to do this efficiently, instead of a `dict` of `list`s + a `dict` of keys.